# Calling AWS Python Lambda function from React Native

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, react-native

Is it possible to call a python lambda function from aws using react native? I'm trying to do data processing using python code. The react native will send some data to the python lambda function ,after analyze the data and the python lambda function will return me the result. Im new to this, because of different programming language so im not sure does it work or not.

Comment: Usually you would invoke lambda through API gateway. Have you consider that?